# Good heuristic to decide whether something is a new item or just a typo?

Tags: string, input, heuristics

Let's say you have a list of 500 school names.

You ask the user: "Which school do you attend?"

Now the input of the user may be one of the schools you already registered (likely), or some other school (unlikely, but possible).

I would like to apply some kind of "similarity metric" to the input against the existing names to decide whether the input is a typo of an already registered school or just a different school.

What is a good metric for that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching